# How to extract a String which is inside the Script tag of a pagesource

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a webpage e.g www.educaxx.com. After checking the pagesource I can see a script is written. This script is writtrn inside the head tag of the page.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
          if ( /\.eduxx\.com/g.test( document.domain ) ) {
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'eduxx.com']);
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-48621467-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);    
          _gaq.push(['jiveTracker._setAccount', 'UA-1066095-1']);
          _gaq.push(['jiveTracker._trackPageview']);
       }
      </script>
```

I want to find the string "_gaq" from this webpage using selenium `webdriver`? How can i make it possible with `JavascriptExecutor` ?

Comment: Can you get hold of above script tag in Java? If yes, then you can simply use regex to extract _gaq from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the page source and store it in a string, then you can use the below code, might be self descriptive,

```
    ArrayList<String> value_to_get= new ArrayList<String>();
    String  regex= "(\\W|^)_gaq(\\W|$)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(page_source);

        while(m.find()) {

            if(!value_to_get.contains(m.group())){
            value_to_get.add(m.group())     
        }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but at String  regex= "(\W|^)your-exact-word-to-match(\W|$)"; But here i'm getting compilation exception i.e "Invalid Escape Sequence(valid ones are \b \t  \n etc) "

Comment: Regex is working now. But m.find() is returning false.

Comment: Yes sure ,  String  regex= "(\\W|^)your-exact-word-to-match(\\W|$)";

Comment: You mean String regex= "(\\W|^)_gaq(\\W|$)"; ?

Comment: Sorry, Yes this one only  String regex= "(\\W|^)_gaq(\\W|$)";

Comment: Changed the code accordingly. The Group(1) i early specified is wrong. it is Group().

Answer (score 0):

It can done this way also in java:-

```
     String page_source =  wd.getPageSource();
     String  check_value= "_gaq";
     if ( page_source.contains(check_value))
     {
         System.out.println(" event is fired on URL :- "+wd.getCurrentUrl());
     }
     else{
         System.out.println(" event is not fired on URL :- "+wd.getCurrentUrl());
     }
```

But how can it be done with JavascriptExecutor using selenium webdriver?